# unmet dependencies op-jre:i386

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I tried to install some programs but i got the following errors:

```
    [...]
Selecting previously unselected package op-jre:i386.
    (Reading database ... 281698 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack op-jre_1.5.0-14_i386.deb ...
    Unpacking op-jre:i386 (1.5.0-14) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of op-jre:i386:
     op-jre:i386 depends on libxp6.

    dpkg: error processing package op-jre:i386 (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     op-jre:i386
    . cleaning up temporary files

    Installation complete.
```

The program isn't working and when i try

```
zeena@S:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 op-jre:i386 : Depends: libxp6:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I already tried sudo apt-get autoremove, update and upgrade but that won't help.
Any ideas what else i can try?

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: It removed op-jre:i386 (1.5.0-14) but still got the same problem  when i try to install the program